# how to slide text from left to right instead of images in this code?

Tags: javascript

i have this code here for sliding images but i wanted to do the same thing for sliding text instead of images but it is not working with me when i tried it , so any one can do it for me text slider moving from left to right instead of image slider without mouse click? and thanks in advance

```js
 var mainImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");

//Create image array
var imageArray = ["Life is what happens to us while we are making other plans","Life is what happens to us while we are making other plans","Life is what happens to us while we are making other plans"];

//Set up array index
var imageIndex = 0;

function changeImage() {
    
    mainImage.setAttribute("src",imageArray[imageIndex]);
    imageIndex++;
    
    
    if(imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
        
        imageIndex = 0;

      
}


    }



//Create function to cycle through images
mainImage.onclick = changeImage
   


//Call cycle function
var intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImage,3000);

mainImage.onclick = function () {
    clearInterval(intervalHandle);  
}
```

```css
h1 {
            text-align: center;
        }
        #mainImage {

            padding-left: 350px;
            padding-top: 40px;
        }
```

```html
//<img id="mainImage" src="images/D.png" />
```

Comment: There is no attribute `p` in `img`. Plese explain what you want to do?

Comment: @Ashish i want this code works for sliding text instead of images , i just did an edit for code

Comment: I have added the answer, you can check.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `HTML DOM innerHTML Property`.

Create an element with `id="text"` change `document.getElementById("text").innerHTML`

```js
var textElement = document.getElementById("text");

//Create image array
var imageArray = ["Life is what happens to us while we are making other plans","Life is what happens to us while we are making other plans2","Life is what happens to us while we are making other plans3"];

//Set up array index
var imageIndex = 0;

function changeImage() {
    textElement.innerHTML = imageArray[imageIndex]
    imageIndex++;

    if(imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
        imageIndex = 0;     
    }
}



//Create function to cycle through images
textElement.onclick = changeImage
   


//Call cycle function
var intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImage,3000);

textElement.onclick = function () {
    clearInterval(intervalHandle);  
}
```

```css
h1 {
            text-align: center;
        }
        #mainImage {

            padding-left: 350px;
            padding-top: 40px;
        }
```

```html
<p id="text"></p>
```

Comment: thank you ! but can it be sliding from left to right?

Comment: You need to write css using keyframes.

Comment: is it possible with js?